# How can you add the variable of an iterator in a for loop to reference a numeric property in an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a Json from a JsonResult in Asp MVC that looks like this:

```
{"Nombres":["Daniel Aguilar Delgado","Francisco Javier Aguilera Candelas"],"Materias":{"0":["Herramientas Legales contra la Delincuencia Organizada","Derechos humanos, debido proceso y función policial","Perfiles delictivos"],"1":["Criminalística y tecnologías","Cultura de la legalidad","Perspectiva de género","La función de seguridad pública en el marco de la reforma constitucional al sistema procesal penal","Prevención social de la violencia y la delincuencia","Actualización jurisprudencial en materia penal","Valores éticos y jurídicos"]},"NumMaterias":2,"NumPreguntas":10}
```

Now as you can see the two properties inside the object "Materias" are simply numeric properties, but I can't do something like:

```
var datapoints = [];
        var data = [];
        for (i = 0; i < response.Nombres.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < response.Materias.i.length; j++) {
                datapoints.push({ y: 1, label: response.Nombres[i] });
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < response.Materias.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < response.Materias.i.length; i++) {
                data.push({
                    type: "stackedColumn",
                    legendText: response.Materias.i[j],
                    name: response.Materias.i[j],
                    showInLegend: true,
                    dataPoints: datapoints
                })
            }
        }
```

(I'm trying, as you may have noticed, to format the json response to use it with CanvasJs, but without luck).
How can you access a numeric property using a for loop like that, is it even possible? I've tried to google it but most references say you should use a for in loop, however when I do that CanvasJs throws an error saying replace is not a function, i. e. I've done:

```
for (var property in response.Materias) {
                data.push({
                    type: "stackedColumn",
                    legendText: response.Materias[property],
                    name: response.Materias[property],
```

But that didn't work either.
I'll appreciate any help because I'm in kind of a hurry with this.

Comment: response.Materias has no length, you need to use a for-in loop.

Comment: `for (var i=0, mx=Object.keys(response.Materias).length; i < mx; i++) {` kill the inner loop, then use `response.Materias[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use Numbers to access properties using the dot syntax. Try using the bracket syntax instead:

```
for (j = 0; j < response.Materias[i].length; j++) {
    datapoints.push({ y: 1, label: response.Nombres[i] });
}
```

Then apply the same treatment in your second loop.

Comment: no, string and numbers are interchangeable for that in JS, that's not the issue

Comment: My bad @dandavis. Because a Number can not be used to access a property using the dot syntax, I incorrectly assumed it would also not work using the bracket syntax.

Comment: That did the trick, I tried to comment earlier but my network was down. Sorry. I knew it was just a matter of syntax and I just couldn't remember.